# WordPress - can't get value from metabox in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have trouble to get a value from a metabox in a custom post type.

Here is how I register metabox in custom post type:

```
register_post_type( 'poslovi-newsletter',
    array(
         'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Poslovi newsletter' ),
         'hierarchical' => false,
         'singular_name' => __( 'Posalji newsletter' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-email',
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_bez_oznaka_text_metabox'
        )
);
```

And this is how I handle displaying that metabox on custom post type in dashboard, saving data, etc...

```
function add_bez_oznaka_text_metabox() {
    add_meta_box('poslovi_newsletter_meta', 'Tekst mejla za korisnike bez oznaka', 'bez_oznaka_textarea', 'poslovi-newsletter', 'normal', 'default');   
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_bez_oznaka_text_metabox' );

function bez_oznaka_textarea( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'poslovi_newsletter_nonce' );
    $poslovi_newsletter_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="meta-textarea" class="poslovi_newsletter-row-title"><?php _e( 'Tekst mejla', 'poslovi_newsletter-textdomain' )?></label> 
        <textarea name="meta-textarea" id="meta-textarea" style="width: 100%; min-height: 200px;"><?php if ( isset ( $poslovi_newsletter_stored_meta['meta-textarea'] ) ) echo $poslovi_newsletter_stored_meta['meta-textarea'][0]; ?></textarea>
    </p>
    <?php
}

function poslovi_newsletter_meta_save( $post_id ) {

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'poslovi_newsletter_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'poslovi_newsletter_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-textarea' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-textarea', $_POST[ 'meta-textarea' ] );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'poslovi_newsletter_meta_save' );
```

Now, that all works fine. When I add new post and enter data, it saves post with that data. When I var_dump post for example, I see everything, content, title, date, etc., but I don't see any meta data.

Also, when I do this (let's say I want to get meta data from post with id 37422)

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta( 37422, 'meta-textarea', true );
var_dump($meta_value);
```

I get vlaue of: string(0) ""

I probably done wrong some part of code that is responsible for saving part, but can't figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've fiddled a bit with your custom post type and it works for me.

I've created a page template to output all the posts from the `poslovi-newsletter` post type. The php part looks like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'poslovi-newsletter',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
$out = '';
if ($posts->have_posts()){
    while ($posts->have_posts()){
        $posts->the_post();

        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

        $out.= '<div class="test">'.$meta['meta-textarea'][0].'</div>';
    }
}
else{
    echo '<p>' . __('No Posts Found.') . '</p>';
}
?>

<?php echo $out;?>
```

So your post meta value is in an array that has, among other things key with the name `meta-textarea`, and in that key the value is an array that has a single key with your desired value

```
Array (
    [meta-textarea] => Array ( 
                        [0] => Tessst 
                    )
)
```

I've typed in 'Tessst' to check if it's working.

Hope this helps :)